# nginx настройка стартовой страницы

Tags: nginx

При настройке столкнулся с проблемой.
есть сайт в локальной сети 192.168.139.31/fcgi/wtma.wt
nginx настроен следующим образом
location / {
proxy_pass http://192.168.139.31;

как мне в nginx настроить что бы по умолчанию открывался сайт mysite.example.ru/fcgi/wtma.wt

хотелось бы что бы пользователь введя mysite.example.ru попадал сразу на mysite.example.ru//fcgi/wtma.wt

полный конфиг nginx:

```
    server {
    if ($host = mysite.example.ru) {
        return 307 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.example.ru;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.example.ru-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.example.rus-error.log;
        set_real_ip_from х.х.х.х;
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;


}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name mysite.example.ru;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.example.ru-ssl-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.example.ru-ssl-error.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.example.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.example.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl.crt/dhparams.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/html/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.139.31;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout       600;
        proxy_send_timeout          600;
        proxy_read_timeout          600;
        send_timeout                600;
    }
}
```

Comment: сделайте редирект location = / { return 301 /fcgi/wtma.wt; }

Answer (score 0):

решение

```
 location / {
        rewrite ^/$ /fcgi/wtma.wt redirect;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.139.31;
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).